# How to adjust opacity of TMS layer in google maps api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have the following TMS layer in google maps:

```
KantoRapidMapType.prototype.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256,256);
KantoRapidMapType.prototype.maxZoom = 17;
KantoRapidMapType.prototype.name = "Rapid Survey";
KantoRapidMapType.prototype.alt = "Rapid Survey Map in Kanto Plain";
KantoRapidMapType.prototype.getTile = function(tile, zoom, ownerDocument) {
  var img = ownerDocument.createElement("img");
  img.style.width = this.tileSize.width + "px";
  img.style.height = this.tileSize.height + "px";
  var y = (1<<zoom) - tile.y - 1;
  img.src = "http://www.finds.jp/ws/tms/"
    +"1.0.0/"
    +"Kanto_Rapid-900913/"
    + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + y + ".png";
  return img;
};
```

I add the TMS layer with:
    var kanto = new KantoRapidMapType();
    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, kanto);

How do I set the opacity of this layer? When I try anything like:

```
kanto.setOpacity(0.5)
```

I just get undefined because kanto does not have a setOpacity function. I notice that the ImageMapType appears to support setOpacity, but am not sure if I could wrap or convert what I have to it.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the method `getTileUrl` instead of `getTile`:

```
  KantoRapidMapType=function(opts){
    //apply supplied options
    opts=opts||{};
    for(var k in opts){
      this[k]=opts[k];
    }
  }
  KantoRapidMapType.prototype.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256,256);
  KantoRapidMapType.prototype.maxZoom = 17;
  KantoRapidMapType.prototype.name = "Rapid Survey";
  KantoRapidMapType.prototype.alt = "Rapid Survey Map in Kanto Plain";
  KantoRapidMapType.prototype.getTileUrl=function(tile,zoom){
    var y = (1<<zoom) - tile.y - 1;
      return("http://www.finds.jp/ws/tms/"
              +"1.0.0/"
              +"Kanto_Rapid-900913/"
              + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + y + ".png");
  }
```

To inherit the methods of the `ImageMapType` create a new instance of ImageMapType and pass a new instance of KantoRapidMapType as argument:

```
var kanto = new google.maps.ImageMapType(new KantoRapidMapType());
//set the opacity
kanto.setOpacity(.5);
```

or directly pass the opacity with the options:

```
var kanto = new google.maps.ImageMapType(new KantoRapidMapType({opacity:.5}));
```